# SSIS ERROR : The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to load data from a MYSQL DB to SQL server DB using SSIS and i am facing a problem where it is giving me the following Error :

> [OLE DB Destination MyTable [137]] Error: There was an error with OLE
> DB Destination MyTable.Inputs[OLE DB Destination
> Input].Columns[update_at] on OLE DB Destination MyTable.Inputs[OLE DB
> Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed
> because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

the data types are as follows

MYSQL = timestamp

SQL = DATETIME

Default dates are stored as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the source database and there are no NULL values in the source database.

I have tried a multitude of solutions listed online but none of them seem to work for my project.

Any idea on what could be causing this ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

I have tried a multitude of solutions listed online but none of them seem to work for my project.

Comment: Put another way - can I force sql-server to accept a datetime of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ?

Comment: @P.Salmon, I guess it can't be done, since it's an invalid datetime. I'd consider updating the source db instead.

Comment: @jarlh I'd be surprised if ssis can't transform as it goes.

Comment: Hi.  You will get better help if you let us know what you HAVE tried.  You'll need to transform the 0 values into null which certainly can be done in SSIS.

Comment: SSIS does have transformations in the Dataflow task, @P.Salmon . Presumbly the OP would be better importing their datetime column as a ISO formatted string, and then using a derived column transformation to `NULL` the "zero dates" and convert the remainder to a date (and time) data type.

Comment: If it helps, try_convert() will return a NULL without throwing an error.  For example:  Select try_convert(datetime,'0000-00-00 00:00:00')

Comment: let me ask this its an idea i have in my head 
is there a way to use a derived column to replace the 0000-00-00 00:00:00 with 1900-01-01 and still keep it a date field without having to convert it to string and then back to date again after the data is read from the source  as it is a live DB and i cant alter the current records i only have read access to the source DB?

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions and support appreciate it. found my own little solution derived from all the other ideas by using a derived column to transfer die dates to a unicode string and import them to the database  and then just converting and replacing the "bad" values as the process continues. 

sitting with a different dilemma at the moment and a different error. anyone have a possible fix for this one ?

[ODBC Source MyTable [40]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '01004'. Native Error Code: 0. [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.47-log]